# UICollectionViewFlowLayout ignoring section insets for items of different heights - bug or expected?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using UICollectionViewFlowLayout and wanted to apply section insets like below. All my items have the same width but varying heights. The insets work when items within the same section are the same height but not when they are different heights in the same section. Is this expected behaviour for this layout? Do I need to subclass and make a custom one or is something missing?

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    CGFloat big = 30;
    CGFloat small = 10;

    if (section < 5) {
        insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, big, 0, small);
    } else {
        insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, small, 0, big);
    }

    return insets;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using setting the collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex: and collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex: methods of your collection view delegate?

Comment: They are always the same, so I just had them set as property values. Just tried returning via the delegate and played with different values. No change.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be possible with varying heights, so I made the cells full width and mange the padding logic inside the cell class itself.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason the UICollectionViewFlowLayout has the behaviour to center the cells if you have a single item each row. It ignores the section insets then.

You can solve this issue by overriding the UICollectionViewFlowLayout and change the following two methods:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self fixLayoutAttributeInsets:attribute];

    return attribute;
}
```

And

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *results = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute in results)
    {
        [self fixLayoutAttributeInsets:attribute];
    }

    return results;
}
```

The magic:

```
- (void)fixLayoutAttributeInsets:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attribute
{
    if ([attribute representedElementKind])
    { //nil means it is a cell, we do not want to change the headers/footers, etc
        return;
    }

    //Get the correct section insets
    UIEdgeInsets sectionInsets;

    if ([[[self collectionView] delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:)])
    {
        sectionInsets = [(id<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>)[[self collectionView] delegate] collectionView:[self collectionView] layout:self insetForSectionAtIndex:[[attribute indexPath] section]];
    }
    else
    {
        sectionInsets = [self sectionInset];
    }

    //Adjust the x position of the view, the size should be correct or else do more stuff here
    CGRect frame = [attribute frame];

    frame.origin.x = sectionInsets.left;

    [attribute setFrame:frame];
}
```

This solution does not work (and is not needed) if you have multiple cells on a single row so you should check for that case with a boolean or whatever you like... This is just a simple example for this scenario